# Best practices and suggestions for experienced iOS developers starting OS X development?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, ios, macos

What are your suggestions / best practices / ideas for places to start for experienced iOS developers who are interested in beginning OS X development? Specifically, since an experienced iOS developer is already familiar with Objective-C, XCode, Interface Builder, and Cocoa Touch, where should such developers get started for such a transition?

Comment: You should type your question title in the search box and poke around, there are a few duplicates of this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895646/books-on-development-of-mac-os-x-applications

Answer (score 2):

I think the first major architectural difference to learn is the use of bindings in Cocoa.

If you've used KVO seriously in your iOS work then I think this should be fairly intuitive but either way look at the NSController classes as they can significantly change the way you structure your view-controller interactions.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/WhatAreBindings.html

You'll have garbage collection available on OS X and should learn how to read code which uses it but you can certainly continue to manage reference counts yourself and that's might be easier than going the other direction and having to learn to give up garbage collection to work on iOS.

UIView and NSView are different and you'll have some work to do learning the different view frameworks. For example by default (0, 0) is in the top left of a UIView and the bottom left of an NSView (take advantage of NSView's isFlipped method to work with familiar coordinates).

Comment: +1, except it should be "top left" of a UIView. Man, "top right" would kill everyone but those accustomed to right-to-left languages!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tip that will save you some trouble if you plan to distribute via the Mac AppStore:

**Don't set up your iTunesConnect app metadata too early!**

or if you do, use a disposable bundle ID, App Name and SKU number, as you have a 120 day grace period in which to upload the app after which your app entry will be deleted and you will not be able to reuse that metadata.

This feature is most likely to prevent squatting, but 4 months isn't that long in a software dev project and you don't want to have to explain to your boss why you can't use your own brand name or why the graphics assets have to be redone.